# MPDF hanging spinning with no PDF generated

Tags: php, pdf, mpdf

I have a problem with PDF generation using MPDF 6.
The project consists of many data forms stored in a database.
And we have the reports section where users can generate PDFs from the search results.
Some tables are generating PDFs just fine. Others show the spinner hanging for very long time without a result.
The memory limit is set very high (550M) but still, even small data tables get stuck at the spinner.
What am I doing wrong ?
Thank you in advance !

Comment: Please see: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Looking into documentation usually helps. https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/slow.html

Comment: Faced the same problem. The reason was I inserted UTF8 content (which I generate dynamically) into CP1251-encoded template.

When I changed template encoding into UTF8, mpdf generated the file.